# Pasar una consulta u otra dependiendo el boton

Tags: php, javascript, variables

Es mi primera pregunta y espero saber explicarme.

Tengo dos inputs mediante por un boton le paso el dato a una variable de Session con la cual relleno una consulta sql, si lleno una variable hago una consulta y si lleno la otra, se ejecuta otra consulta por metodo Post en los botones de los inputs. Esto lo he conseguido.....

Mi problema viene cuando intento que mediante un enter en el input realice el mismo trabajo, no me funciona en uno de los botones, lo raro es que el otro si :(

```
<form  id="formulario" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="buscarCodigo">
                            Buscar Codigo
                        </button> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" >                                                 
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="buscaDescripcion">
                            Buscar Descripcion
                        </button>                                       
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div style="text-align: right">
                        <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="250 px" height="150 px" >
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </form>
```

Este es el html

por scripts paso los datos a otra hoja php y lleno la tabla con las consultas obtenidas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buscarCodigo").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            data:'codigo=' + $('#codigo').val(),
            url:"php/globales.php",

            success:function(){
                $('#tablaDatatable').load('tablas/tablaArticulos.php');
                alertify.success("COMPLETADO");
            }
            });
        });



    $("#buscaDescripcion").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            data:'descripcion=' + $('#descripcion').val(),
            url:"php/globales.php",

            success:function(){
                $('#tablaDatatable').load('tablas/tablaArticulos.php');
                alertify.success("COMPLETADO");

            }

        });

    });
});
</script>
```

ahora creo dos scripts para que hagan lo mismo que el botón

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#descripcion').keypress(function(e){
       if(e.which === 13){//Enter key pressed
           $('#buscaDescripcion').click();//Trigger search button click event
       }
   });

    $('#codigo').keypress(function(e){
       if(e.which === 13){//Enter key pressed
           $('#buscarCodigo').click();//Trigger search button click event
       }
   });
})
</script>
```

aqui estan las consultas

```
<?php 

class articulo
{

    public function articulos()
    {
        if( isset($_SESSION['codigo'])){

        $cod = $_SESSION['codigo'];

        $sql ="SELECT A.CODART CODIGO, A.DESCART DESCRIPCION, A.PARAM2 ACABADO,  STOCK.UNIDADES STOCK,  A.CIJAM_PALABRASCLAVE 'PALABRAS_CLAVE', A.CODPRO PROVEEDOR
                FROM ARTICULO AS A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCKALM AS STOCK ON A.CODART = STOCK.CODART
                AND STOCK.CODALM = 'GN' WHERE A.CODART LIKE '%".$cod."%' OR DESCART LIKE '%".$cod."%'";
            } 

            return $sql;
            unset($_SESSION['codigo']);
    }

    public function descripcion(){

        if (isset($_SESSION['descripcion'])){

            $desc = $_SESSION['descripcion'];

            $sql ="SELECT A.CODART CODIGO, A.DESCART DESCRIPCION, A.PARAM2 ACABADO,  STOCK.UNIDADES STOCK,  A.CIJAM_PALABRASCLAVE 'PALABRAS_CLAVE', A.CODPRO PROVEEDOR
                FROM ARTICULO AS A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCKALM AS STOCK ON A.CODART = STOCK.CODART
                AND STOCK.CODALM = 'GN' WHERE A.DESCART LIKE '%".$desc."%'";

                return $sql;
                unset($_SESSION['descripcion']);

        }
    }

}
?>
```

y por ultimo el momento de ser llamadas que me funciona siempre salvo cuando aprieto enter en el input de descripción que coge el código que esta vacío :(

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "../consultas/articulo.php";
$art=new articulo();
if (isset($_SESSION['codigo'])){

    $sql=$art->articulos();

}elseif (isset($_SESSION['descripcion'])){

    $sql=$art->descripcion();
}   
require_once "../consultas/conexion/conexion.php";
$obj= new conectar();
$conexion=$obj->conexion();


$result=sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql);
?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, haberme explicado bien y desde ya, muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo

Saludos

Comment: Cuando se presiona ENTER, antes de ejecutar clic del botón agrega `e.preventDefault();` para evitar el _comportamiento normal_ del formulario.

Comment: Esta ha sido la solución, gracias @Triby... Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La manera que yo encontrado hasta ahora, aclaro no se si sea la mejor, es hacer 2 Formulario en cada uno un input de manera independiente, el cambio en el diseño es minimo.

```
<form  id="formulario1" method="POST">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="buscarCodigo">
               Buscar Codigo
            </button> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" >
</form>
<from id="formulario2" method="POST">
     </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="buscaDescripcion">
            Buscar Descripcion
            </button>                                       
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" >
            </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <div style="text-align: right">
                   <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="250 px" height="150 px" >
                  </div>
           </div>              
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar!! voy a probarlo, lo que me parece raro es que en un input funcione tanto con el boton como con el enter y en el otro solo me funcione con el boton si pulso enter, coge el parametro del primer input que claro... esta vacio. Pruebo tu solucion y te cuento.... gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he solucionado el error con la respuesta de Triby que ha sido añadir el e.preventDefault() en el evento enter.

Gracias!!